# Keep the value of a select option if the page refresh inside a php

Tags: php

I made a select option like below which takes the values from my database and display them. I am trying to make an option to remain selected if the submit button is pressed.

```
 $autor = mysql_query (' SELECT * FROM autor ORDER BY  autor ASC ') ;

 while( $liniea = mysql_fetch_array ( $autor )) {

 echo '<option value='.$liniea["id"].' if(isset($_POST["selautor"]) &&
 $_POST["selautor"]=='.$liniea["id"].'{echo "selected";} >
 '.$liniea['autor'].'</option>';}

 echo '</select>';
```

Comment: `' if(isset($_POST["selautor"]) && $_POST["selautor"]=='` is considered a string and not a php-code

Comment: and how should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there.... Try this (I assumed your request is good and returns rows)

```
 $autor = mysql_query (' SELECT * FROM autor ORDER BY  autor ASC ') ;
 echo '<select>';
 while( $liniea = mysql_fetch_array ( $autor )) {
     $selected = '';
     if(isset($_POST["selautor"]) && $_POST["selautor"] == $liniea["id"]) {
         $selected = "selected";
     }

     echo '<option value='.$liniea["id"].' ' . $selected. '>'.$liniea['autor'].'</option>';
 }

 echo '</select>';
```